# Android Compose Navigation Screen Duplicate Calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

If you put the viewModel parameter in PostScreen and call the function in viewModel from PostScreen, the PostScreen screen itself will be called repeatedly.

If I remove the function in viewModel and run it, everything works fine.

```kotlin
    private val postViewModel: PostViewModel by viewModels()
    private val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()


    @Composable
    fun NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = NavigationRoute.postRoute) {
            composable(NavigationRoute.postRoute) {
                PostScreen(postViewModel, userViewModel)
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.settingsRoute) {
                SettingsScreen(userViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
    
@Composable
fun PostScreen(postViewModel: PostViewModel) {
    Log.d("test","PostScreen")
    postViewModel.listPostBasicInfo()
}
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    Log.d("test","SettingsScreen")
}
```

Comment: PostScreen
SettingsScreen
PostScreen
PostScreen
PostScreen
SettingsScreen

The log appears like this

Comment: Please provide relevant code. As of now, no one would be able to pin point the exact issue. What is the expected behaviour? What's unexpected which is occurring? What does the `listPostBasicInfo` method do?

Comment: The listPostBasicInfo function does not do anything. The problem is that it uses a function in ViewModel.

Comment: Please provide the expected behaviour, along with the unexpected behaviour which is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly mean what your question is,
but i assume the problem is **post screen called again and again**

**Reason -**
due to the nature of jetpack compose, it recompose often times,
can cause the

```
Log.d("test","PostScreen")
```

to recompose multiple times,

**Fix - ** use Launched effect to do calculations or data fetching (calling business logic)

**modified code**

```
@Composable
fun PostScreen(postViewModel: PostViewModel) {
LaunchedEffect(key = Unit){
Log.d("test","PostScreen")
postViewModel.listPostBasicInfo()
}
}
```

hope the answer helps, if not, please clarify me the question , I've always looking forward to help you.

Comment: PostScreen is called repeatedly

Comment: This answer fixes nothing. Please suggest edits to questions in comments, instead of writing an answer.